Nestjs GraphQL createUnionType for queries returning single object & array of objects
I have GraphqQL API created with Nestjs. I'm trying to use union types for returning exceptions.
export const CountryUnion = createUnionType({
  name: 'CountryUnion',
  types: () => [Country, BaseException] as const,
  resolveType(value) {
    if (value.errorCode) {
      return BaseException;
    }
    return Country;
  },
});

using it in the resolver
  @Query(() => CountryUnion)
  @UseGuards(PermissionGuard)
  country(@Args('id', { type: () => Int }) id: number) {
    return this.countryService.findOne(id);
  }

If user is not authorized, PermissionGuard throws UnauthorizedException. I have a global UnauthorizedExceptionFilterto catch it. It returns a BaseException;
@Catch(UnauthorizedException)
export class UnauthorizedExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const gqlHost = GqlArgumentsHost.create(host);
    return new BaseException(exception.message, '1234');
  }
}

In this countryquery, it works very good;
query country($countryId: Int!){
  country(id: $countryId){
    ... on Country{
      id
      name
    }

    ... on BaseException{
      errorCode
      message
    }
  }
}

{
  "data": {
    "country": {
      "errorCode": "1234",
      "message": "You must have country right"
    }
  }
}

However, countries query returns [Country]. So, exception filter must return [BaseException] this time. Is it possible to handle both queries with the same exception filter bu just updating createUnionType?
tried like this;
  @Query(() => [CountryUnion])
  @UseGuards(PermissionGuard)
  async countries(
    @Args('name', { type: () => String, nullable: true }) name: string,
  ) {
    return await this.countryService.findAll(name);
  }

But did not work. It says Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field \"Query.countries\".
